# Use a categorical column to order the dataframe according to an array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

I have an array like this:

```
['A 100', 'A 200', 'A 300', 'A 400', 'A 500', 'B 100', 'B 200', 'B 300', 'B 400']
```

I also have a dataframe like this:

```
BIN      CA      SUM
100       B      B 100
300       A      A 300
300       B      B 300
400       B      B 400
400       A      A 400
200       B      B 200
100       A      A 100
200       A      A 200
```

I want to use `pd.Categorical` to order the column dataframe according to the array.

The expected output is:

```
BIN      CA      SUM
100       A      A 100
200       A      A 200
300       A      A 300
400       A      A 400
100       B      B 100
200       B      B 200
300       B      B 300
400       B      B 400
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) to convert the `SUM` column to categorical column having order, then [`sort`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) the values:

```
df['SUM'] = pd.Categorical(df['SUM'], categories=arr, ordered=True)
df.sort_values('SUM')
```

Alternatively you can create a dictionary that maps the items in `arr` to their sorting order then [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) this dictionary on `SUM` column and use [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to get the indices that would sort the dataframe:

```
dct = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(arr)}
df.iloc[np.argsort(df['SUM'].map(dct))]
```

---

```
   BIN CA    SUM
6  100  A  A 100
7  200  A  A 200
1  300  A  A 300
4  400  A  A 400
0  100  B  B 100
5  200  B  B 200
2  300  B  B 300
3  400  B  B 400
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `CA` column as `index` then finally `reindex` based on your `specified list`

```py
d = [[100, 'B' , 'B 100'],
[300, 'A' , 'A 300'],
[300, 'B' , 'B 300'],
[400, 'B' , 'B 400'],
[400, 'A' , 'A 400'],
[200, 'B' , 'B 200'],
[100, 'A' , 'A 100'],
[200, 'A',  'A 200']]

df = pd.DataFrame(d , columns=['BIN', 'CA', 'SUM'])

l =['A 100', 'A 200', 'A 300', 'A 400', 'A 500', 'B 100', 'B 200', 'B 300', 'B 400']

df2 = df.set_index('SUM').reindex(l)
df2.dropna(inplace=True) #dropna is required of your list has some element that is not in the original dataframe, in this case A 500
df2
```

```
SUM      BIN    CA
    
A 100   100.0   A
A 200   200.0   A
A 300   300.0   A
A 400   400.0   A
B 100   100.0   B
B 200   200.0   B
B 300   300.0   B
B 400   400.0   B
``
```